# What use is a weapon with lead +1 in Edge RPG?

Tags: weapons, edge-rpg

I'm playing in the Edge RPG. Besides the weapon being more concealable, I can't find a reason for a martial character to use a weapon with lead +1 (that is, effectively, a light weapon) instead of a weapon with lead +2 (that is, effectively, a one handed weapon).

At first I assumed the rules would make using weapons with a lead +1 more viable than using a higher lead weapon during two-weapon fighting, but the rules don't seem to care what types of weapons are wielded during two-weapon fighting. (Oddly, the rules *also* don't seem to care *how many* weapons are wielded for extra attacks, but that's beside the point.)

The only possibility I can see is that such weapons are just options for characters without *any* martial specialization, yet it seems like there should be some *advantage* to — or, at least, no matter its obscurity, some *reason* for — a highly trained warrior to wield a weapon with lead +1. So, besides appearances ("Light weapons look awesome…") and concealability ("…and I can fit them in my boot!"), is there *any* reason for a warrior to fight using a weapon with a lead +1?

Comment: **Answerers:** We're looking for answers based on knowledge of ***Edge RPG***, the game being asked about. To avoid having an answer removed, make sure it avoids guessing and clearly shows how familiar you are with the game.

Comment: While I am unable to find a free copy of or excerpt from this game, I believe I have found the game itself: http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/93185/Edge-Role-Playing-Game&affiliate_id=35526 If anyone has become so curious that buying the book would be worth it.

Comment: I do know that in real-world combat, bigger is better. Knights only ever really used swords as a backup, when they lost their polearm. Sword training is only prolific because it was considered a stepping stone to properly using more dangerous weapons, so everyone learned how to use a sword. Many actual combatants would never consider a smaller weapon than a sword unless they needed to conceal it. (per an instructor from [Swordwind](https://www.swordwind.org/)) I don't know if this was an attempt by Outrider to be marginally more realistic or not.

Answer (score 10):

I went ahead and contacted Outrider Studios through their [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/OutriderStudiosPress/) and received this response:

> Conceal-ability is the big advantage. The other is that you can throw the weapon without using the Throwblade power.

It would seem that's the extent of small weapon benefits.

When asked about intent, they clarified:

> ...A lot of players do not use a +1 weapon as their main or Edgeforged weapon, but as a backup plan. You never know when you might need a small weapon to throw or keep hidden. We kept them as +1 instead of +0.
>
> Our thinking is that you can kill someone even with a small knife, so the +1 was justified.